# Where to ask about an electrical shaver type (!= product recommendation)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking into buying a high-end electrical shaver which I can use not only for my beard, but also my head. However, electrical shavers are designed to collect the cut hair below the rotating or oscillating blades, which works fine when cutting hair on the face. Using the shaver on the top and the back of the head causes it to be held upside down which makes it questionable whether it still works fine and without a multiplication of blade wearout which might be caused by the same hair being cut multiple times instead of falling below the blade.

Can I ask this question on engineering.SO? Is there a better place?

Like I mentioned in the title, I'm not looking for a product recommendation, but a design type (rotary or foil-type design or else) which fits the needs best and an argument that the use doesn't cause unnecessary wearout.

Comment: Went ahead and asked the question at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23122/electrical-shaver-type-for-face-and-head

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Engineering.SE would be a good place to put this because it doesn't really have to do with engineering. If you were going to design your own, then certainly, but if you are just buying a product, that isn't a good choice.

I would not recommend this question for Stack Exchange at all, you might be able to find a better, and more specialized forum somewhere else online. However, if you really think it will fit on the SE network, you should try [Lifehacks.SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/). I would recommend posting there, and if the moderators decide it is not a good fit, asking on a different platform outside of SE.

If you have an idea for a new SE site to deal with these types of questions about personal hygiene products, you can suggest one at the [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) site.