# Where can I ask questions about beauty tips on SE?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where users can ask questions about skin care, cosmetics and beauty tips for both sexes?

Comment: I guess lifehacks.se it too much of a stretch ...

Comment: I don't think lifehacks would welcome beauty tips @rene! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for tips using common materials not specifically designed for the purpose, Lifehacks.SE will work for you.

If you want to know what chemicals are used to achieve certain results, you might try Chemistry.SE

If you are just looking to find a good beauty product, this probably does not belong on any currently existing Stack Exchange site. That said, I recently answered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313741/400527) by a user asking about expensive electric razors. If you want, you can talk to them and create a new Stack Exchange site for beauty and personal hygiene products. If you have a specific format for how questions can be narrowed down so that they aren't too open ended, you can suggest a site on the Area 51 page.

Comment: If you're down voting, please leave a comment to explain what is wrong with the post so I can improve it

Comment: TBH, the A51 option seems the best, assuming you can get the traction. Not entirely sold on lifehacks as an option tho

Comment: @Journeyman According to the Lifehacks help menu, on topic questions are: seeking uncommon solutions to common physical problems,
asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to achieve a certain task or solve a specific problem, or
looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an obvious solution. Questions should not be about using products in the way they were designed to be used

Comment: So if you are trying to use something not for the purpose it was designed for, that is on topic