# Why is there no beauty/cosmetics SE site?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Why is there no SE site dedicated to questions about beauty, cosmetics, skin care and related questions and answers?

There’s millions of different beauty products, but almost all information you can find on the subjects are sales pitches from various companies. This seems like a perfect opportunity for SE to serve a massive market.

There is a [related meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316421) discussing alternative SE sites, but it doesn’t explain why there is no dedicated beauty Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for the hint, I didn’t know about [area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). It sounds like a complex process to get a site set up, with a big obstacle being the gap between subject matter experts and people familiar with the SE format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beauty has been [proposed previously](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57538/beauty) on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). The proposal failed though. It had sample questions such as

> "What are the differences between BB cream and CC cream?"

and

> "What are the tips to prevent dry skin in winter?"

Either it didn't attract enough support or the Q&A seemed like it would just become a spam magnet site. Stack Exchange sites should not simply be adverts for hundreds of companies products. Even [this question about where can I ask about beauty tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316421/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-beauty-tips-on-se) has two deleted spam answers.

Similar proposals on [grooming and body care](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11037/merge-hair-facial-hair-shaving-and-beauty-into-personal-hygiene-heal) also failed.

Comment: Thanks for putting together this answer and explaining the reasons.